# Restrict Control / UIElement within screen boundaries

Tags: c#, xaml, canvas, windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro

I have a `Canvas` as the base of my app, and it has several controls which the user can move, rotate and scale using their respective `ManipulationDelta`'s.

The problem is that the user can accidentally carry the control out of the `Canvas` or screen boundary while moving the control around with their finger.

How do I restrict the movement of these controls within the `Canvas` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check the [`ToolWindow`](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/WinRTXamlToolkit.Shared/Controls/ToolWindow/ToolWindow.cs) control and the [`FlickBehavior`](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/WinRTXamlToolkit.Shared/Controls/Behaviors/FlickBehavior.cs) in WinRT XAML Toolkit for inspiration.

It's pretty basic overall. If you don't do inertia it might be something like this:

```
if (x < 0)
    x = 0;
if (x > _canvas.ActualWidth - this.AssociatedObject.ActualWidth)
    x = _canvas.ActualWidth - this.AssociatedObject.ActualWidth;
if (y < 0)
    y = 0;
if (y > _canvas.ActualHeight - this.AssociatedObject.ActualHeight)
    y = _canvas.ActualHeight - this.AssociatedObject.ActualHeight;
```

Once you rotate or scale - you need to do some matrix transform operations to get the bounding rectangle. Fortunately the platform has some methods to make it easy for you - namely the `TransformToVisual()` and `TransformPoint()` methods. I also have a helper class with en extension method that makes it even easier - check out [`VisualTreeHelperExtensions.GetBoundingRect()`](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/WinRTXamlToolkit.Shared/Controls/Extensions/VisualTreeHelperExtensions.cs).

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the bounding rectangle of a given element
/// relative to a given other element or visual root
/// if relativeTo is null or not specified.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// Note that the bounding box is calculated based on the corners of the element relative to itself,
/// so e.g. a bounding box of a rotated ellipse will be larger than necessary and in general
/// bounding boxes of elements with transforms applied to them will often be calculated incorrectly.
/// </remarks>
/// <param name="dob">The starting element.</param>
/// <param name="relativeTo">The relative to element.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
/// <exception cref="System.InvalidOperationException">Element not in visual tree.</exception>
public static Rect GetBoundingRect(this FrameworkElement dob, FrameworkElement relativeTo = null)
{
    if (DesignMode.DesignModeEnabled)
    {
        return Rect.Empty;
    }

    if (relativeTo == null)
    {
        relativeTo = Window.Current.Content as FrameworkElement;
    }

    if (relativeTo == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Element not in visual tree.");
    }

    if (dob == relativeTo)
    {
        return new Rect(0, 0, relativeTo.ActualWidth, relativeTo.ActualHeight);
    }

    var ancestors = dob.GetAncestors().ToArray();

    if (!ancestors.Contains(relativeTo))
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Element not in visual tree.");
    }

    var topLeft =
        dob
            .TransformToVisual(relativeTo)
            .TransformPoint(new Point());
    var topRight =
        dob
            .TransformToVisual(relativeTo)
            .TransformPoint(
                new Point(
                    dob.ActualWidth,
                    0));
    var bottomLeft =
        dob
            .TransformToVisual(relativeTo)
            .TransformPoint(
                new Point(
                    0,
                    dob.ActualHeight));
    var bottomRight =
        dob
            .TransformToVisual(relativeTo)
            .TransformPoint(
                new Point(
                    dob.ActualWidth,
                    dob.ActualHeight));

    var minX = new[] { topLeft.X, topRight.X, bottomLeft.X, bottomRight.X }.Min();
    var maxX = new[] { topLeft.X, topRight.X, bottomLeft.X, bottomRight.X }.Max();
    var minY = new[] { topLeft.Y, topRight.Y, bottomLeft.Y, bottomRight.Y }.Min();
    var maxY = new[] { topLeft.Y, topRight.Y, bottomLeft.Y, bottomRight.Y }.Max();

    return new Rect(minX, minY, maxX - minX, maxY - minY);
}
```

Once you get the bounding rect - you can use its dimensions instead of `ActualWidth`/`ActualHeight` and X&Y of the manipulated object to determine where it can or cannot go.

Comment: Yes that works when the controls are aligned with the screen boundaries. But when the controls are rotated by an angle, adding `ActualWidth` to `x` where x is the top-left point does not give the top-right point.